# RxPy - Turn Live Twitter Stream into Rx Observable?

Tags: python, reactive-programming, tweepy, reactivex, rx-py

I followed along this [great tutorial](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/) to leverage a live Twitter stream in Python using tweepy. This will print Tweets in live time that mention RxJava, RxPy, RxScala, or ReactiveX.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from rx import Observable, Observer

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
access_token = "CONFIDENTIAL"
access_token_secret = "CONFIDENTIAL"
consumer_key = "CONFIDENTIAL"
consumer_secret = "CONFIDENTIAL"


#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class TweetObserver(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = TweetObserver()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
    stream.filter(track=['rxjava','rxpy','reactivex','rxscala'])
```

This is the perfect candidate to turn into a [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/) Observable via [RxPy](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY). But how exactly do I turn this into a hot source `Observable`? I cannot seem to find documentation anywhere on how to perform an `Observable.create()`...

Comment: I remembered that I can accomplish this with a Subject, and I've been successful there. But still wondering if I can do this Subject-free...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out some time ago. You have to define a function that manipulates a passed `Observer` argument. Then you pass that to `Observable.create()`.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import json
from rx import Observable

# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
access_token = "PUT YOURS HERE"
access_token_secret = "PUT YOURS HERE"
consumer_key = "PUT YOURS HERE"
consumer_secret = "PUT YOURS HERE"


def tweets_for(topics):
    def observe_tweets(observer):
        class TweetListener(StreamListener):
            def on_data(self, data):
                observer.on_next(data)
                return True

            def on_error(self, status):
                observer.on_error(status)

        # This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
        l = TweetListener()
        auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        stream = Stream(auth, l)
        stream.filter(track=topics)

    return Observable.create(observe_tweets).share()


topics = ['Britain', 'France']

tweets_for(topics) \
    .map(lambda d: json.loads(d)) \
    .subscribe(on_next=lambda s: print(s), on_error=lambda e: print(e))
```